# WPRobot Cannot Copy Images from IIS Server

Tags: php, wordpress, web-scraping, iis

I am trying to test a scraping setup targeting sites of my own using servers of my own, but when I do I get an error from WPRobot saying "Error: Inserting post failed. Cannot create attachment file in "/home/myapp/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/162153879_434009211024473_384527521975744737_n.jpg" Please set correct permissions." I typically get this notice if the source does not allow other sites to copy its content using curl requests. To get around this I setup a Puppeteer script to act as a proxy by taking screenshots of image files on the source website (in this case Instagram), but now I get the same error when trying to download the screenshots from my own IIS server.

I have added nothing to my server that is intended to prevent anyone from being able to curl image files from it. In fact, there are several sites that were hosted on the same server recently. WPRobot never had a problem downloading any images from those. I have changed nothing other than uploading a Node.js application to the default website directory after deleting the old websites for the purpose of using this server to test the app before my account with the host is suspended in a few days.

What would cause images on an IIS 10 server to not be accessible via curl on the default website? Here is an example image for which WPRobot claims correct permissions are not set http://85.17.219.113/images/2021/3/505648a2-3404-c3e6-618f0fa50fd3.jpg? Could this be due to using an IP address instead of a domain name? Could the length of the file name be an issue?

Also: the image is only 92kb in size. I mention this because I have had issues with WPRobot displaying the same error when trying to download large files, but this file is nowhere near large enough to trigger that.

UPDATE: This appears to be a problem with file_get_contents and/or file_put_contents in PHP and NOT curl. For instance, the following results in an error:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://85.17.219.113/images/2021/3/505648a2-3404-c3e6-618f0fa50fd3.jpg');
try{
    file_put_contents('test.jpg', file_get_contents($page));
    echo 'file downloaded';
}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

That code does not create a file and does not echo an error message either, but when I turned on error reporting I got this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: file_get_contents(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\sources\test.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\sources\test.php(16): file_get_contents('\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\sources\test.php on line 16
```

I cannot explain this error. How can that URL translate to a filename with null bytes?

This downloads the image just fine:

```
$url = 'http://85.17.219.113/images/2021/3/505648a2-3404-c3e6-618f0fa50fd3.jpg';

// Image path
$img = 'test.jpg';

// Save image
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen($img, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Now I need to find the function in WPRobot that is used to cache images and save them to the file system. Does anyone know where that function is in WPRobot? It would be nice to know exactly how that plugin saves images.

Comment: Could this have something to do with curl having a hard time with javascript? I just realized that even thought the RSS feeds is accessible via an XML file that I had to add special code to my server.js file just to make it load XML and image files. Otherwise it would only load server.js. That was a shock to me because I have never seen such an issue with physical files before. Could it be that having server.js create the XML files renders it unreadable to curl and if so, how do I make the server load physical field BEFORE server.js?

Comment: Maybe a better question would be how to change the load order for a node.js site so that certain types of files are loaded before javascript files. Such as .xml and .jpg being loaded before any .js files.

Comment: I tried removing images from the description fields of the RSS items to see if the problem is just images or the XML file in general. Weird result is that I still get an error related to an image file despite loading the feed and finding none in it. Perhaps WPRobot is trying to crawl a cached version of the feed on its own end?

Comment: THANK GOD (is what I would say if religious)! I just ran a curl test on my PC and was able to get the entire XML file, so obviously that is not the problem. I was really worried for a second.

Comment: Running a test on my local machine using curl in PHP and just printing the result as an echo resulted in all the random gibberish one would expect from doing just that. Maybe WPRobot is not using curl for images. Maybe they are using file_get_contents?

Comment: I found one case where someone didn't have correct permissions for Apache to write to the file, but I know that is not the case here because every WPRobot can save images from any other feed to the same folder.

Comment: Now it looks like a different bug in WP Robot might be to blame. This other bug causes edits not to be saved when saving campaigns. Edits such as changing the feed URL. Usually you can see if the campaign was updated by reloading it but sometimes it says it was updated but when you run it , the old URL is uses, and the next time you check the settings the old URL is there again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be WPRobot itself not updating the new feed URL. As a result it was still trying to use the one that included the original Instagram image file URLs. Usually this bug does not take so long to detect. Usually when I load the campaign options it will show the old URL if the update did not work and all you have to do is keep pasting the new URL and hitting the update button until it finally works. I had done this several times and reloading the page showed the new URL in the text area, but for some reason I loaded the page an hour later and the old one showed up.

This really is a horrible bug in WPRobot. When you have to change the URLs in 10-20 campaigns it can take an hour to do it because you keep having to do it over and over again until it finally works.